# Row Numeric (Percent) Formatting in RHandsontable

Tags: r, rhandsontable

I need to format rows of a pivoted table using RHandsontable.  Column formatting is super straightforward, but hot_row() does not provide the same flexibility as hot_col().

Has anyone figured out a way to format this...

```
library(rhandsontable)
df <- data.frame(q1=c(1,0.2),q2=c(2,0.3),q3=c(3,0.4),q4=c(4,0.5))
rownames(df) <- c('Amt','Pct')
rhandsontable(df)
```

[no formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QQnj.png)

...to display ints (1,2,3,4) for the first row (Amt) and percentages (20%,30%,40%,50%) for the second row (Pct)?

[formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/628ME.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

For anyone interested - pct_row and int_row are arbitrarily-named arguments.  Those args are exposed in instance.params.  I can then check if the row is a part of that argument and treat it accordingly in td.innerHTML.

```
library(rhandsontable)
df <- data.frame(q1=c(1,0.2),q2=c(2,0.3),q3=c(3,0.4),q4=c(4,0.5))
rownames(df) <- c('Amt','Pct')  
rhandsontable(df,pct_row=1,int_row=0) %>%
       hot_cols(renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
           Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
           if (instance.params && instance.params.pct_row === row) {
               td.innerHTML = `${Number.parseFloat(value*100)}%`
           } else if (instance.params && instance.params.int_row === row) {
               td.innerHTML = `${value}`
           }
         }")
```

Many thanks to this post for connecting some dots for me...
https://forum.handsontable.com/t/percentage-formatting/5172/3

Comment: See related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73906753/how-to-format-different-rows-differently-in-rhandsontable for formatting multiple rows, in a similar manner