# How to format different rows differently in rhandsontable

Tags: html, r, shiny, rhandsontable

I'm building a user input table using `rhandsontable(`) package. I'm trying to format some rows as integers and some as percentages, based on what I found in [Row Numeric (Percent) Formatting in RHandsontable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71428147/row-numeric-percent-formatting-in-rhandsontable). But in that example only one row is integer formatted and the other row is percentage formatted. I need to format 2 rows as integers and 2 rows as percentages, as shown in the image below. In the code below I've tried different things like `rhandsontable(...pct_row= c(2,3), int_row= c(0,1)...)` but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

The user will never be able to add rows, but the user can add (and eventually delete) columns.

[image]

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,2,3,4),check.names = FALSE)

rownames(mydata) <- c('Term A','Term B','Term C','Term D') 

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("mytable"),
  textInput('NewCol', 'Enter new column name'),
  actionButton("goButton", "Update Table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mytable = renderRHandsontable(df())
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewCol!="" && !is.null(input$NewCol) && input$goButton>0){
      newcol <- data.frame(NROW(mydata))
      names(newcol) <- input$NewCol
      mydata <<- cbind(mydata, newcol)
    }
    rhandsontable(mydata, 
                  rowHeaderWidth = 100, 
                  pct_row= 2, 
                  int_row= 0
                  )%>%
      
      hot_cols(
        colWidths = 80, 
        renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
           Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
           if (instance.params && instance.params.pct_row === row) {
               td.innerHTML = `${Number.parseFloat(value*100)}%`
           } else if (instance.params && instance.params.int_row === row) {
               td.innerHTML = `${value}`
           }
         }"
        )
      
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observe(if (!is.null(input$mytable)) mydata <<- hot_to_r(input$mytable))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution in the java script section of the code under `hot_cols(...)`. This works fine for me because the number of rows are limited. This is an extension to include multiple rows of the solution provided in [Row Numeric (Percent) Formatting in RHandsontable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71428147/row-numeric-percent-formatting-in-rhandsontable). Will continue fiddling to find a cleaner solution.

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,2,3,4),check.names = FALSE)

rownames(mydata) <- c('Term A','Term B','Term C','Term D') 

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("mytable"),
  textInput('NewCol', 'Enter new column name'),
  actionButton("goButton", "Update Table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mytable = renderRHandsontable(df())
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewCol!="" && !is.null(input$NewCol) && input$goButton>0){
      newcol <- data.frame(NROW(mydata))
      names(newcol) <- input$NewCol
      mydata <<- cbind(mydata, newcol)
    }
    rhandsontable(mydata,rowHeaderWidth = 100)%>%
      
      hot_cols(
        colWidths = 80, 
        renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
           Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
           if (instance.params && 0 === row || instance.params && 1 === row) {         // 0 & 1 for 1st 2 rows of table
               td.innerHTML = `${value}`
           } else if (instance.params && 2 === row || instance.params && 3 === row) {  // 2 & 3 for 2nd 2 rows of table
               td.innerHTML = `${Number.parseFloat(value*100)}%`
           }
         }"
        )
      
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observe(if (!is.null(input$mytable)) mydata <<- hot_to_r(input$mytable))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```